# Javascript & jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have no idea how to search for this so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to figure out how this code works :

```
if ($("#main .oc .dc .image").removeAttr("style"), 1120 > wW && wW > 920)
    $("#main .oc .dc .image").css({
        width: Math.round(.3 * wW) + "px",
        left: "calc(50% - " + Math.round(.3 * wW / 4) + "px)"
    });
```

My questions is -

What does the comma between `.removeAttr("style")` and `1120 > wW` do in the condition of this statement?

And how exactly action gets executed, the -

```
$("#main .oc .dc .image").css(
```

before figure brackets and lack of quotes on css properties -

```
{width:Math.round(.3*wW)+"px",left:"calc(50% - "+Math.round(.3*wW/4)+"px)"}
```

confuses me.

Comment: I think it's a trick, the comma operator returns the right hand expression to the `if` statement

Comment: @adeneo true - only the last condition is checked when they are provided comma separated: https://jsfiddle.net/bgav45wm/. I'd still call it bad practice though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - it most certainly is, there's no reason to remove that attribute that way, it could be placed on it's own line before the `if` condition, someone was just being "clever".

Comment: Someone found a way to write some "clever" code that only serves the purpose of reducing readability.

Comment: And by "clever" they are literally reducing the code by one line...by putting it in the next line. Useless.

Comment: Tell me if i'm wrong. So 'If statement' won't be executed, if there's two, separated by comma, operands. And first one is false?

Comment: @maksem - no, the first one doesn't matter, the right hand expression is returned

Comment: What could be a use of this "clever" trick, if the left-hand expression isn't evaluated?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it _is_ evaluated. The result of it is thrown away, however. So it will do the removal of the attribute, however, the return value will not matter because the value of the boolean evaluation will be returned. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question, m aksem...
And thanks for the explanation, @vlaz...

I've learned something new!
I made a test snippet to go throught this:

```js
var wW = 1000;

$("#test1").on("click",function(){
    if ($("#main .oc .dc .image").removeAttr("style"), 1120 > wW && wW > 920)
        $("#main .oc .dc .image").css({
            width: Math.round(.3 * wW) + "px",
            left: "calc(50% - " + Math.round(.3 * wW / 4) + "px)"
        });
});

$("#test2").on("click",function(){
    if (1120 > wW && wW > 920)
        $("#main .oc .dc .image").css({
            width: Math.round(.3 * wW) + "px",
            left: "calc(50% - " + Math.round(.3 * wW / 4) + "px)"
        });
});

$("#test3").on("click",function(){
    if (false, 1120 > wW && wW > 920)
        $("#main .oc .dc .image").css({
            width: Math.round(.3 * wW) + "px",
            left: "calc(50% - " + Math.round(.3 * wW / 4) + "px)"
        });
});
```

```css
.image{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    main
    <div class="oc">
        oc
        <div class="dc">
            dc
            <div class="image" style="color:red;">
                image
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="test1" value="Test 1 - Execute full condition"><br>
<input type="button" id="test2" value="Test 2 - Execute condition without the left hand part"><br>
<input type="button" id="test3" value="Test 3 - Execute condition with a FALSE in the left hand part"><br>
```

So the thing is that there is two arguments in the condition, coma separated.
There may be more.

In "test 1", the left hand condition is executed (the red color, defined in the inline style attribute IS removed), but the boolean result (which would be true) is not considered in the `if` statement.

Only the last condition will be.
"Test 3" proves this, since left hand condition is a `false`.

Notice that I defined `wW` as 1000 in order to make the right hand condition to evaluate as `true` (and therefore, see the effect).
I also defined a CSS `position:absolute` for `.image`.

I agree with @Jason P about the fact that this "trick" reduces readability a lot.
I don't see any useful case. Still, it's a good thing to know!